# Why does merge sort run in $O(n^2)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, asymptotics, landau-notation

I have been learning about Big O, Big Omega, and Big Theta. I have been reading many SO questions and answers to get a better understanding of the notations. From my understanding, it seems that **Big O is the upper bound** running time/space of the algorithm, **Big Omega is the lower bound** running time/space of the algorithm and **Big Theta is like the in between of the two**.

This particular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/big-theta-notation-what-exactly-does-big-theta-represent?lq=1) on SO stumbled me with the following statement

> For example, merge sort worst case is both ${\cal O}(n\log n$) and $\Omega(n\log n)$ -
>   and thus is also $\Theta(n\log n)$, but it is also ${\cal O}(n^2)$, since $n^2$ is
>   asymptotically "bigger" than it. However, it is NOT $\Theta(n^2)$, Since
>   the algorithm is not $\Omega(n^2)$

I thought merge sort is ${\cal O}(n\log n)$ but it seems it is also ${\cal O}(n^2)$ because $n^2$ is asymptotically bigger than it. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Comment: For mergesort, you even have a bound $O(2^n)$. It is an *upper bound*, nobody said it is in any way "best possible".

Comment: We both agree that $10 < 20$. Also, $10 < 30$. In much the same way, $f(n)$ can be $O(g(n))$ and $O(h(n))$ at the same time. On the other hand, if $x = y$ and $x = z$, we know also $y = z$. Similarly, if $f(n)$ is $\Theta(g(n))$ and $\Theta(h(n))$, we know $g(n)$ is $\Theta(h(n))$ and $h(n)$ is $\Theta(g(n))$.

Comment: O(n^2) does not necessarily mean running time would be O(n^2).It Just mean running time is less than or equal to O(n^2).in this case O(n^2) represents that running time would be less than O(n^2) as it is not asymptotically tight.For further details see my answer.

Comment: All answers are available in [our reference questions on asymptotics](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/846#846).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a mathematical matter and not the matter of the worst case running time. First you have to know that Big O does not represent worst case running time of some algorithms. Big O comes from mathematics and it represents an asymptotic upper bound for some mathematical functions.

[image]

You can see that the graph of $n^2$ is always above the graph of $n\log n$. so you can say $n^2$ is an upper bound on $n\log n$ as the value of $n\log n$ is always less than $n^2$. So mathematically you can say $n\log n=O(n^2)$. Similarly graphs of all $n^i$ for $i\geq 2$ are always above the graph of $n\log n$. So you can say $n\log n$ is also $O(n^3),O(n^4),O(n^5),\ldots$

But one thing you have to remember that though $n\log n$ is $O(n^2)$ but $n\log n$ is not $\Theta(n^2)$, because $n\log n$ is not $\Omega(n^2)$. Mathematically you can say $n\log n$ is $o(n^2)$.

If you still have any confusion regarding my answer, you can ask me here.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider a simpler situation. For numbers $x,y$, say that $x = S(y)$ if $x \leq y$, that $x = L(y)$ if $x \geq y$, and that $x = E(y)$ if both $x = S(y)$ and $x = L(y)$. Since $1 = S(1)$ and $1 = L(1)$, it is the case that $1 = E(1)$. But it is also the case that $1 = S(2)$.

The situation with running times is similar. Given two positive functions $f,g$, we say that $f = O(g)$ if $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ for some $C > 0$ (independent of $n$), that $f = \Omega(g)$ if $f(n) \geq cg(n)$ for some $c > 0$, and that $f = \Theta(G)$ if $f = O(g)$ and $f = \Omega(g)$. For example $2n = O(n)$ since $2n \leq 2 \cdot n$ and $2n = \Omega(n)$ since $2n \geq n$, and so $2n = \Theta(n)$. It is also the case that $2n = O(n^2)$ since $2n \leq 2\cdot n^2$.

For numbers we have the important property of transitivity: $x \leq y \leq z$ implies $x \leq z$. The same relation holds for functions: if $f = O(g)$ and $g = O(h)$ then $f = O(h)$; indeed, if $f \leq C_1 g$ and $g \leq C_2 h$ then $f \leq C_1C_2 h$. The running time of merge sort $T(n)$ is $\Theta(n\log n)$, and $n\log n = O(n^2)$, and so $T(n) = O(n^2)$, but $T(n)$ is not $\Omega(n^2)$ and so $T(n)$ is not $\Theta(n^2)$. The class $\Theta(n\log n)$ is a *tight* bound on $T(n)$; $O(n^2)$ is an upper bound which is not tight.

Comment: Does this mean that the worst possible running time for mergesort is O(nlogn) but the possible running time for mergesort is O(infinity) ??

Comment: Not at all. The running time $T(n)$ of mergesort is bounded by $cn\log n \leq T(n) \leq Cn\log n$ for some constants $0<c<C$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, $f=\cal O(g)$ means that $f$ *grows no faster* than $g$. Clearly, $n \log n$ grows no faster than $n^2$ and we can write $n \log n = \cal O(n^2)$. Symmetrically, $f=\cal \Omega(g)$ means that $f$ *grows at least as fast* as $g$. $n \log n$ does not grow at least as fast as $n^2$ so we have the inequality $n \log n \neq \cal \Omega (n^2)$. When $f$ grows no faster than $g$ and at least as fast as $g$, it makes sense to say that $f$ grows as fast as $g$; write $f=\cal \Theta(g)$.

To answer your question, notice that *grows no faster than* is *transitive*. For numbers $x,y,z$ we all know that if $x\lt y$ and $y\lt z$ then this implies that $x\lt z$. Now for functions $f,g,h$, we have that if $f=\cal O(g)$ and $g=\cal O(h)$ then this implies that $f=\cal (h)$. Let $f=\cal O(n\log n)$. Since $n \log n = \cal O(n^2)$, we have that $f = \cal O(n^2)$.

This should hopefully help you better understand Big O notation. You can prove transitivity of $\cal O$ using the formal definition:

> For functions $f,g$, we say that $f$ is Big O of $g$ (write $f=\cal O(g)$) if there exist constants $n_0,c \gt 0$ such that $f\le c\times g$ whenever $n\ge n_0$.

This means that starting at some point along the $x$ axis (we call it $n_0$) the function $f$ is always bounded above by a constant multiple of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not find any contradiction between your (said) understanding and the answer from StackOverflow you posted. It seems your problem is at the level of your understanding of *upper* bound and *lower* bound.

In this context of algorithm complexity, upper bound means *cannot be asymptotically worse than*. As such all algorithms are $O(\infty)$. Lower bound means *cannot be asymptotically better than*. As such all algorithms are $\Omega(0)$.

However for those algorithms for which there exists an $O(f(n))$ and an $\Omega(f(n))$, where $f(n)$ is some function of $n$, there also exists a $\Theta(f(n))$. So we notice that of the three only $\Theta$ is unique.